# Stored procedure from query results SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables. One is sales table (`header`), the other is sales line (`lines`).

What I want to do is to find out if any records in sales table or sales line were modified. And if they were modified I want to insert the whole sales order into another table. I use a column in the database `ModifiedDateTime` (the changes in sales line do not affect modification date in salestable and vice versa).

For example - sales table :

```
SalesID DeliveryAddress ModifiedDatetime
   1        Street1       2017-04-20 2:00:00
   2        Street3       2017-04-19 3:00:00
```

Sales Line

```
SalesID ItemId Qty ModifiedDateTime
 1       100    2     2017-04-20 3:00:00
 1       101    3     2017-04-20 2:00:00
 2       100    5     2017-04-19 1:00:00
```

So I have a stored procedure which selects records from these tables and inserts them into other tables. It uses modified date time to know which records had been modified. The thing I want to do is to insert the whole order and its lines in to integration tables.

What I do now is

```
Insert into IntegrationSalesTable (salesid, deliveryaddress, modifieddatetime)
    select salesid, deliveryaddress, modifieddatetime 
    from salestable 
    where modifieddatetime > 2017-04-20 2:30:00
```

And for salesline

```
 Insert into IntegrationSalesLine(salesid, itemid, qty, modifieddatetime)
     select salesid, itemid, qty, modifieddatetime 
     from salestable 
     where modifieddatetime > 2017-04-20 2:30:00
```

Right now, I get  `IntegrationSalesTable` empty - and `IntegrationSalesLine` has this row:

```
SalesID ItemId Qty ModifiedDateTime
  1       100    2     2017-04-20 3:00:00
```

What I want to achieve:

IntegrationSalesTable:

```
  SalesID DeliveryAddress ModifiedDatetime
   1        Street1       2017-04-20 2:00:00
```

IntegrationSalesLine:

```
SalesID ItemId Qty ModifiedDateTime
 1       100    2     2017-04-20 3:00:00
 1       101    3     2017-04-20 2:00:00
```

I have an idea that I need to select all modified sales orders in lines and table and then run a query using that data. But I cannot think of ways to do it. Any suggestions how can I achieve this result?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the last table. Where did the sale at 1:00:00 go? Why does an entry at 2:00:00 show up there, when the query to insertexplicitly gives a date at 2:30:00 onwards? Also, why do the fields in `IntegrationSalesTable` do not match the format in the `SalesTable`?

Comment: Also can you assume that all sales after a certain date&time are modified? I think you need both creation date + modification date to detect a modified entry otherwise (or field containing a flag)

Comment: Yeah i did a mistake in table structure. Sorry about that that is fixed. About last tables its the results i want to achieve but dont know how :) Results of current query are above that

Comment: I think there is still an error. Shouldn't `IntegrationSalesTable` contain `DeliveryAddress` instead of `ItemId`? On what grounds can you decide that the entry at 1:00:00 is not modified, but the ones at 2:00:00 and 3:00:00 are? Perhaps @anand is right, and you only have to change the date in the query to 1:30:00.

Comment: Also I dont get why the `IntegrationSalesTable` stays empty, as the row `   2        Street3       2017-04-19 3:00:00` should match the insert query.

Comment: Yeah sorry fixed again :). I want to insert the whole sales order (according to sales id) and sales lines. IF any of the lines or the header has been modified.

Comment: @user2893780 Where did the time come from 2:30:00?

Comment: Beginning to understand. Can the `SalesLine` contain modified items, without the `SalesTable`containing modified items? (i.e. can the dates be different for a single sales id?)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177564.aspx might help you

Comment: The time comes from the last time query has been run. Yes the dates can be different for different lines in salesline for the same salesid

Comment: But will the date in salestable be different if an entry in salesline has been modified? It would make things much easier

Comment: I know it would make things easier but the reality is when you modify a salesline salestable date does not change

Comment: See my answer. If the assumption i made is correct, you should change your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need. It selects all entries for a `SalesID` where the dates in `salesline` are not matching the date in `salestable`

```
use testdb;

-- This stores all the SalesID's where something changed
DECLARE @modsalesids TABLE
(
   SalesID INT 
)

-- Select SalesID's where dates are different
insert into @modsalesids(SalesID)
select st.SalesID from salestable st
join salesline sl on st.SalesID=sl.SalesID 
where 
-- use '<>' if you want to include _all_ changed dates, or > when you want only changes where the item list changed after the sale
    sl.ModifiedDateTime <> st.ModifiedDateTime 


-- Remove duplicate SalesID's, make sure to keep the ';' 
;

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesID ORDER BY SalesID) AS RN
FROM @modsalesids
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1

-- Select records for the modified salesIds
insert into integrationsalesline(SalesID, ItemId, Qty, ModifiedDateTime) 
select SalesID, ItemId, Qty, ModifiedDateTime from salesline where SalesID in (SELECT SalesID from @modsalesids);
insert into integrationsalestable(SalesID, DeliveryAddress, ModifiedDateTime) 
select SalesID, DeliveryAddress, ModifiedDateTime from salestable where SalesID in (SELECT SalesID from @modsalesids);

-- Debug stuff

select * from @modsalesids;

select * from integrationsalesline;
select * from integrationsalestable;
```

If you are curious, here is the [source](http://dotnetmob.com/delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server/) to the part that removes duplicates.
This is how I setup a test case:

```
-- create testdb;

--create table salestable (
--  SalesID INT,
--  DeliveryAddress VARCHAR(200),
--  ModifiedDateTime VARCHAR(200)
--)

--create table salesline (
--   SalesID INT,
--   ItemId INT,
--   Qty INT,
--   ModifiedDateTime VARCHAR(200)
--)

--create table integrationsalestable (
--  SalesID INT,
--  DeliveryAddress VARCHAR(200),
--  ModifiedDateTime VARCHAR(200)
--)

--create table integrationsalesline (
--   SalesID INT,
--   ItemId INT,
--   Qty INT,
--   ModifiedDateTime VARCHAR(200)
--)

--insert INTO salestable  values(1,'Street1','2017-04-20 2:00:00')
--insert INTO salestable  values(2,'Street3','2017-04-20 3:00:00')

--insert INTO salesline values(1, 100, 2, '2017-04-20 3:00:00')
--insert INTO salesline values(1, 107, 7, '2017-04-20 3:00:00')
--insert INTO salesline values(1, 101, 3, '2017-04-20 2:00:00')
--insert INTO salesline values(2, 100, 5, '2017-04-20 1:00:00')
```